# Does ARC release malloc'ed memory for you?

Tags: objective-c, memory, memory-management, malloc, automatic-ref-counting

Automatic Reference Counting releases Objective-C objects that have been allocated. What about primitive variables like `char *`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No as per the [llvm document on ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#general)

> Automatic Reference Counting implements automatic memory management for Objective-C objects and blocks, freeing the programmer from the need explicitly insert retains and releases. It does not provide a cycle collector; users must explicitly manage lifetime instead.

and

> A retainable object pointer (or retainable pointer) is a value of a retainable object pointer type (retainable type). There are three kinds of retainable object pointer types:
>
> - block pointers (formed by applying the caret (^) declarator sigil to a function type)
> - Objective-C object pointers (id, Class, NSFoo*, etc.)
> - typedefs  marked with __attribute__((NSObject))
>
> Other pointer types, such as int* and CFStringRef, are not subject to ARC's semantics and
>      restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

ARC directly release only ObjC objects (not `char*`, `void*`, `int*` ...).    However ARC still calls the dealloc method of objects.  So if you have an ObjC object that malloc's up some memory and points a char* at it, and the dealloc method calls free that memory will still get properly disposed of.

Same for Core Foundation objects, you still need to `CFRelease` them.   Even the toll free bridged CF types need manual calls to `CFRelease`.